# Bash Error: Unary Operator Expected

Tags: bash, variables, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a simple Bash script that will execute a command based on user-input. I have some experience with Python, but for some reason, this is giving me issues.

===================

```
*#!/bin/bash
echo "Type one of the following:"
echo " 1 - whoami"
echo " 2 - df"
echo " 3 - date"
echo " 4 - cal"
echo "===> "
read $return_value
if [ $return_value -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo $whoami
elif [ $return_value -eq 2 ]
    then
        echo $df
elif [ $return_value -eq 3 ]
    then
        echo $date
elif [ $return_value -eq 4 ]
    then
        echo $cal
else [ $return_value != 5 ]
    echo "You made an invalid Selection. Exiting."
fi
```

========================================

I continually get this set of errors and I'm at a loss.

```
Type one of the following:
 1 - whoami
 2 - df
 3 - date
 4 - cal
===> 
2
./utilities1.sh: line 10: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./utilities1.sh: line 14: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./utilities1.sh: line 18: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./utilities1.sh: line 22: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./utilities1.sh: line 26: [: !=: unary operator expected
You made an invalid Selection. Exiting.
```

Any advice or tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `read $return_value` with `read return_value`

Comment: good god, i love a simple error. thanks janos. now i have to figure out why the commands are not outputting any information when called.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `read return_value` without `$` sign.

Your commands are not called after selecting an option because `$whoami` is treated as a variable. You probably want `$(whoami)`. The same for the other commands.

Comment: I did not recommend `echo $(whoami)` instead of `whoami`. From `echo $whoami` I just assumed that this was the intention of the user who asked. I corrected his typo, but whether the solution itself is recommended or not is another question.

Comment: By the way I do not know what do you want from me. Indeed, you recommended a better solution. I made clear that there is a difference between `$whoami` and `$(whoami)`. You did not do this, I did not recommended better solution. So again, what is your problem? Is a knowing a more efficient solution for something more important than knowing the difference between `$whoami` and `$(whoami)`?

Comment: Thank you both for all of the input. I got things working with a blend of the suggestions from you both. Now I have to convert the same "problem" to case logic, which SHOULDN'T be too difficult...but I have a degree in poetry, so who knows.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

First, you obviously meant `read return_value` instead of `read $return_value`, to read user input into the variable named `return_value`.
`read $return_value` would read user input into a variable named as the value of `$return_value`. For example if `return_value=x`, then it would read the input into variable `x`. Since `return_value` is not assigned when you run the script, this is hardly what you want. You most certainly want `read return_value`.

Second, instead of `echo $df`, and the others, you probably want to execute those commands.

Also, the value of `$return_value` will be empty if the user simply presses enter, and that again will break the conditionals. So you should double quote it in the `if` and `elif` statements.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type one of the following:"
echo " 1 - whoami"
echo " 2 - df"
echo " 3 - date"
echo " 4 - cal"
echo "===> "
read return_value

if [ "$return_value" -eq 1 ]; then
    whoami
elif [ "$return_value" -eq 2 ]; then
    df
elif [ "$return_value" -eq 3 ]; then
    date
elif [ "$return_value" -eq 4 ]; then
    cal
else [ "$return_value" != 5 ]
    echo "You made an invalid Selection. Exiting."
fi
```

Comment: Just a small note from me: `-eq` is for numerical comparison and `=` for string comparison. In this case here, I do not see the exchange as a problem.

Comment: @Cyrus As I mentioned, I replaced `-eq` with `=` to simplify. It's simpler because it's shorter to type, and it works just as well for this example. If you see a good reason to keep it `-eq`, let me know. In any case I dropped that point, since you objected.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is very unclear and could use more specification about what exactly you want to type.  If you want the user to type "1", then say that, not " 1 - whoami".  I also am unclear about your "*" at the beginning.  Here is a working code, with explanations commented in.  Hope this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type one of the following numbers to"
echo "execute the specified command:"
echo " 1 - whoami"
echo " 2 - df"
echo " 3 - date"
echo " 4 - cal";
echo -n "===> "    #the -n means dont create a newline.. so the input will be after the arrow
read return_value  #remove $
echo "user input = ${return_value}"   #using ${} instead of just $ is good practice unless you have reason
if [ "${return_value}" == "1" ]; then  #sometimes you need = instead, compatibility issues.  but -eq is for integers.
    echo `whoami`                       #surround a command with `command` to execute it
elif [ "${return_value}" == "2" ]; then
    echo `df`
elif [ "${return_value}" == "3" ]; then
    echo `date`
elif [ "${return_value}" == "4" ]; then #don't forget the ";" before "then"
    echo `cal`
else                                    #else doesn't need an argument like if and elif
    echo "You made an invalid Selection. Exiting."
fi
```

example output:

```
me$ ./script.sh 
Type one of the following numbers to
execute the specified command:
 1 - whoami
 2 - df
 3 - date
 4 - cal
===> 1
user input = 1
myusername
```

Comment: I am not sure where the "*" is you're referring to. May be another suggestion from someone else. I see what you mean about it being vague...and I agree. I got it to work; user types in a number and the corresponding command is executed.

Thanks for the effort, by the way! I really appreciate the hive mind genius on this site.